# CSS: Div wrapping a floating element

Tags: html, css, percentage

I have the following:

[image: non-adaptable div]

And I want this:

[image: adaptable div]

If I remove `margin-left: 200px;` from the first I get the second, but my problem is that if I put another div into `<adaptable div>` with `witdh="100%"`, its width become 600px (400px + 200px of floating div), so the div is placed in the "BIG ZONE" and the 400px zone is blank.

How can I do to first fill the 400px zone and then the BIG ZONE?

Example of html: http://jsfiddle.net/wce25bu1/1

```css
.big {
  height: 400px;
  background: #f00;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.float {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: white;
  float: right;
}

.table {
  width: 100%;
}


}
```

```html
<div class="big">
  <div class="float"></div>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Raffle name</th>
        <th>Ticket number</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>This shoud be</td>
        <td>next to the float</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <p>TEXT </p>
</div>
```

I want the table to be aligned with the floating element.

Comment: Please post the HTML and CSS in your question.

Comment: You mean like this? - http://jsfiddle.net/wce25bu1/

Answer (score 1):

This should be fairly easy to create. You **shouldn't** give the table `width:100%` because this will make it fill it's parent element's width and thus it it's wrapped in a new line. What I did is that I changed that to `min-width:400px;` and added a `margin:0 auto;` so that the table is always centered in the area to the left of the white box (in case you want to increase the big red box's width beyond 600px)

Here is the demo jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/wce25bu1/4/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will help you.

```css
.big {
    width:600px;
    background: #f00;
    border:1px solid black;
   
}

.float {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: white;
    float:right;   
}
.table{
    width:350px;
}

.table td{
text-align : center;
}
```

```html
<div class="big">
     <div class="float"></div>
<table class="table">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Raffle name</th>
                        <th>Ticket number</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2nd Feb Raffle</td> <td>0001</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>12nd Feb Raffle</td> <td>0595</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>20nd Feb Raffle</td> <td>1201</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>22nd Feb Raffle</td> <td>0562</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deleniti ad et neque quod nobis tenetur earum voluptatem culpa nihil soluta sequi laborum blanditiis suscipit distinctio tempora quisquam at sapiente consequatur natus minus dolorum labore sint nam rerum atque! Distinctio veniam at natus debitis aperiam perspiciatis vel ipsa officiis voluptatem laudantium magnam obcaecati magni dolor unde aspernatur eaque provident. Perspiciatis officiis quo debitis optio velit explicabo voluptas sint quae cupiditate laudantium. Aut similique exercitationem corporis necessitatibus vero ipsum facere nihil sed odio aliquam nisi placeat eligendi nam. Possimus quae enim aspernatur itaque culpa doloribus architecto dolorum magnam ut laborum. Quidem totam vel earum recusandae velit iste esse eos beatae error dignissimos perspiciatis et natus neque animi maxime quas voluptate explicabo id deleniti adipisci iure sit sequi laudantium laboriosam porro! Ea dolorum quam officia totam repellendus eius facere saepe? Ipsum officia dolore magni dicta dolorem alias doloribus laudantium maiores officiis sequi impedit sapiente recusandae assumenda fugiat quas illo quia dolores molestias optio amet architecto laboriosam modi culpa praesentium magnam vero cumque quis. Aspernatur odio ab asperiores obcaecati perspiciatis alias quod dolor laborum nihil porro ea nemo quam illum ducimus sunt vel exercitationem? Omnis magni dolore sunt dolor magnam inventore quisquam quod quasi non reiciendis eius natus eos molestiae sapiente similique veniam amet officiis ipsam laudantium ad eligendi nesciunt doloribus ipsa quibusdam libero adipisci unde. Rerum voluptate voluptatum voluptatem sapiente quasi odio enim facere nihil quam ratione repudiandae nisi nulla officia hic a illo quae maiores neque voluptatibus quod provident corporis eos in deserunt voluptas saepe dolor possimus vitae deleniti eius! </p>
   
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could work around the issue by giving the width="100%" div a margin-right of -200px (so it fits into the smaller section), or in CSS make the `width: calc(100% - 200px)`.

You shouldn't need to specify a width on the inner div at all, if it is display block it should fit its container div automatically.

Comment: Why do you all use calc for everything :D

Comment: This is what I am trying to avoid. Imagine that the element with 100% width is under the floating element. If I use margin of 200px or calc() it would not fill the entire div, and if I use display: block or just 100% width it would be located under the floating element and the preceding space would not be filled.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using relative and absolute positioning?

UPDATE: I've simply rearranged the container divs. Is this what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/dzhu46Lx/4/

CSS:

```
.float {
 float: right;
 width: 200px; 
 height: 200px;
 background-color: blue;
}
.content{
 position: relative; 
 background-color: red;
 width: 600px;
}
.main-content{
 width: 400px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for giving a so little information. I have updated the thread. Also tried your suggestion but It does not work (at least as I implemented -> http://jsfiddle.net/dzhu46Lx/)

Thanks for trying to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS3 property `calc` to get the table to fill the space:

```
table{
    width: calc(100% - 200px);  
}
```

This will use 100% and remove 200px. This is really the only way to mix percentages and fixed units.

This won't work in IE8 though (http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc).